# Blender 2.92 Beta. Sculpting mode. Tools panel doesnt show brush options

Tags: sculpting

I recently updated to 2.92 Beta to start playing with some of the new options.
Is it there a reason the Tools panel in the properties panel doesn't show the brush properties.

As you can see in the screenshot I am in sculpt mode with one of the Draw Brush selected and nothing shows in the properties panel.[image]

Comment: Possibly just a glitch with the beta but whenever a panel doesn't appear scrolling up or down on it can reset it sometimes.

Comment: Thanks for that.
Scrolling up and down doesn't seem to work but it worthed trying. 
I will report the bug/glitch.

Thanks @NascentSpace.